# Cant get right localtime in C

Tags: c, localtime

Im trying to get the current localtime in C, lets say Italy, I tried the code below but it returns a time three hours earlier than the real one.
For example if executed at 17:34 it will return 14:34, what am I doing wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    
    setenv("TZ", "UTC+1", 1); // Italy is UTC+1
    tzset();
    
    time_t sec = 1634224877; // Just for test
    
    struct tm * end = localtime(&sec);

    // Check for daylight save
    if(end->tm_isdst == 1)
    {
        end->tm_hour += 1;
    }

    printf("Daylight save time?: %d\n", end->tm_isdst);
    
    printf("Time is says: %.2d/%.2d/%d - %.2d:%.2d:%.2d\n", end->tm_mday, end->tm_mon + 1, end->tm_year + 1900,
                                     end->tm_hour, end->tm_min, end->tm_sec);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: What is the actual and expected output from your program itself?

Comment: Your `end->tm_hour += 1;` suggests that you may have misunderstood the purpose of the `tm_isdst` member. (Also, what if `end->tm_hour` was 23?)

Comment: Because the American inventors of Unix did not like America having negative timezone offsets, the offsets in TZ environment variables are negated compared to the usual convention. TZ offsets increase westwards instead of eastwards. The POSIX-style TZ string for Italy is "CET-1CEST-2,M3.5.0/2,M10.5.0/3".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**tl;dr** If you want the time at a location, you have to set `TZ` to a location.

---

1634224877 is 2021-10-14 15:21:17 UTC. [`setenv` takes POSIX time zones which don't work like you think](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/104091/86900). UTC+1 means ***one hour head of UTC***. That is 14:21:17. If you want "UTC+1" you actually ask for `UTC-1`, one hour behind UTC.

But don't ask for `UTC-1`.

---

```
setenv("TZ", "UTC+1", 1); // Italy is UTC+1
```

That comment is not correct. Italy is not UTC+1. Sometimes Italy is UTC+1, sometimes it is UTC+2. In order to know about daylight savings time (and other wacky time zone issues), TZ needs to know your *location*.

Set TZ to the city closest to you, like `Europe/Rome`. Now `localtime` can figure out whether it's daylight savings time or not, you do not need to correct it.

```
int main()
{
    setenv("TZ", "Europe/Rome", 1);
    tzset();

    time_t sec = 1634224877; // Just for test

    struct tm * end = localtime(&sec);

    printf("Daylight savings time?: %d\n", end->tm_isdst);

    printf("Time is says: %.2d/%.2d/%d - %.2d:%.2d:%.2d\n", end->tm_mday, end->tm_mon + 1, end->tm_year + 1900,
                                     end->tm_hour, end->tm_min, end->tm_sec);
}

Daylight savings time?: 1
Time is says: 14/10/2021 - 17:21:17
```

The system that manages time zones is called [tzdata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database). It is a database of locations, their time zone information, daylight savings time switches, and a host of other wacky time zone information. It's what lets your computer know that Rome is usually UTC+1 but should sometimes be UTC+2.

[A list of all tzdata locations can be had on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones), but these do not necessarily match the tzdata installed on your machine.

Answer (score 1):

The `TZ` environment variable value `FOO+1` (I changed it from `UTC+1` to avoid confusion) is interpreted as a standard time zone designated "FOO" with no alternate (daylight savings) zone. The `+1` (the `+` is optional) means that 1 hour needs to be added to the local time to convert it to Coordinated Universal Time (UTC). To specify an alternate (daylight savings) time zone, it is added after the standard time offset, e.g. `FOO+1BAR0`. The offset after the alternate zone can be omitted in which case it defaults to one less than the standard offset, so `FOO+1BAR0` can be shortened to `FOO1BAR`. This means that local time will be 1 hour behind UTC when standard time is in effect and will be UTC when alternate (daylight savings) time is in effect. Optionally, the offset can include minutes or minutes and seconds, e.g. `FOO+01:00BAR+00:00:00`.

Italy uses Central European Time (CET, corresponding to UTC+1) when standard time is in effect (e.g. during winter), and uses Central European Summer Time (CEST, corresponding to UTC+1) when alternate (daylight savings) time is in effect (e.g. during summer). That can be expressed by the `TZ` environment variable value `CET-1CEST-2` or `CET-1CEST`. Notice that the offsets used in the `TZ` environment variable have the opposite sign to the usual convention.

When `TZ` has one of the previously mentioned values with an alternate time (e.g. `CET-1CEST`), it is left up to the system libraries to use some arbitrary (and usually incorrect for most of the world) rule to determine the date and time of transitions between standard time and alternate time. Simple rules for the date and time of exactly two transitions per year can be encoded after the alternate zone designation and offset in the `TZ` variable, separated by commas. The transition date can be specified as M*m*.*n*.*d*, meaning the *d*th day (0 = Sunday, 1 = Monday, ..., 6 = Saturday) of the *n*th week (counting from 1) of the *m*th month (1 = January, ..., 12 = December). *n* = 5 is interpreted as the last *d* day of the month *m*. The transition date can also be specified as J*n* where *n* is the day of the year, not counting February 29 (so March 1 is always day 60). The (optional) transition time can be specified as /*time*, where *time* specifies the current local time on the transition date at which the transition to the other time is made, defaulting to 02:00:00. The *time* value can be abbreviated in the same way as time zone offsets, so /2 is the same as /02:00:00, but no leading plus or minus sign is allowed (by the current standard).

Italy currently operates on EU time zone transition rules (the abolition of which is currently postponed), where the transitions occur at 01:00 UTC and local time advances 1 hour on the last Sunday of March (`M3.5.0`) and retreats 1 hour on the last Sunday of October (`M10.5.0`). For Italy, the local transition times are 02:00:00 in March (advancing to 03:00:00) and 03:00:00 in October (retreating to 02:00:00), so the rules are `M3.5.0/2` and `M10.5.3`. (`M3.5.0/2` can be shortened to `M3.5.0` since it uses the default transition time.)

The following, modified code will work to show time in Italy, at least until the current EU time zone rules are abolished:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    setenv("TZ", "CET-1CEST,M3.5.0,M10.5.0/3", 1); // Italy rules!
    tzset();

    time_t sec;
#if 0
    sec = 1634224877; // Just for test
#else
    sec = time(NULL); // For current time
#endif

    struct tm * end = localtime(&sec);

    printf("Daylight save time?: %d\n", end->tm_isdst);

    printf("Time is says: %.2d/%.2d/%d - %.2d:%.2d:%.2d\n",
           end->tm_mday, end->tm_mon + 1, end->tm_year + 1900,
           end->tm_hour, end->tm_min, end->tm_sec);
}
```

Comment: Your answer is a little confused IMO but it talks about the Mm.n.d format I was also interested in, so thanks for that. Is there some official documentation for that somewhere?

Comment: @Steve. The official standard is POSIX.1-2017 or SUSv4 2018 edition. The latter is freely readable at https://publications.opengroup.org/standards/unix/c181 but you need to create a (free) account to read it. Alternatively, the documentation for the [`TZ` environment variable in the GNU C library](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/TZ-Variable.html) is close enough.